# How to disable the booked time slots from a list of business hour time slots

Tags: c#, asp.net, duration, appointment, timeslots

Friends,

I' working Appointment booking Project, Details are as follows:
Business hour starts from **9:00** to **7:00** with default duration of **30mins**. So, Slots start like (9:00, 9:30, 10:00.... 7:00).

Here, to show the available slots, I'm using the following Logic.

1. Storing all the Slots with **30 min** duration in a list (**LIST A**) like [9:00, 9:30, 10:00, 10:30, ... 7:00]
2. Looping through booked appointments (contains **start and end time**), and if start time is matched with any of **LIST A** elements, I', removing that element from that List. and Loop continues.

Here, the problem is, Consider If appointment is booked **9:30-10:00**. 
Based on my logic, **9:30** is matched with LIST A element, and It will remove 9:30 from that list.

So, available slots will be displayed as [9:00, X ,10:00, 10:30, .... 7:00]. Actually It should be [9:00, 9:30, 10:30, 11:00... 7:00]

Instead of showing available slots **9:00-9:30, 10:30-11:00** it shows **9:00-10:00, 10:30-11** since 9:30 is removed from the list.,

Please help to solve this, or suggest me some alternative approaches for this problem. Badly needed.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are mixing up is, you are taking second slot's start time as first slot's end time. So rather then doing that, what you can do is to store start time and duration.

And to simply compute the end time, you do

```
StartTime.AddMinutes(30);
```

And to add one more comment at end; you are trying to build a very rigid structure. And will face problems if you'd try to extend the application, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, Instead of using Single Dimensional  Array, use Multidimensional array like

```
[[9:00][9:30],[9:30][10:00],[10:00][10:30], .... nth Item]
```

Here, Logic should be like this

```
var start=[start time]
var end=[end time]
var duration=[duration]

for (i=start;i<end;i+=duration)
{
   if(start==A[i][0])
   remove(A[i][0]);
}
A.sort();
return A;
```